# jQuery: Stop submitting form, perform script, continue submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a form, and when I submit him I execute multiple script. Here is my code:

```
$("#RequestCreateForm").submit(function (e) {
    if ($("#RequestCreateForm").validate().checkForm() == false) { return; }

    e.preventDefault();

    //many scripts

    //How to continue submitting?
}
```

Is it possible to continue submitting the form (which is stopped with `e.preventDefault();`) after `//many scripts`?

Thank you

Comment: remove the e.preventDefault(); and you will get your desired effect.

Comment: @Scott that defeats the purpose of his code.

Comment: @Razor - The OP didn't mention whether or not the scripts are done asynchronously.  If they aren't, then you don't need the `e.preventDefault();`.  If they are, then you could fire them off via `$.ajax` and use the completed callback to continue on, which would still mean that you don't need the `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Ok I get that. :) But consider if the scripts are synchronous (which is the assumption since he didnt use ajax or some other asynchronous technique), then the timeframe of the submission would be important. In which case wouldnt preventDefault() be necessary? If you remove it, the form would be submitted before his scripts are done running. (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$("#RequestCreateForm").submit(function (e) {
    if ($("#RequestCreateForm").validate().checkForm() === false) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       //form was NOT ok - optionally add some error script in here

       return false; //for old browsers 
    } else{
       //form was OK - you can add some pre-send script in here
    }

    //$(this).submit(); 
    //you don't have to submit manually if you didn't prevent the default event before
}
```

Comment: This would create an infinite loop and thus triggers an 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.'

Comment: Update the "return;" to "return false;" per Bhanu Krishnan's answer. Also that "==" should be "===".

Comment: **Question has been edited** - *it works now.* Note that you don't have to do `return false;` if you are developing for the modern browsers only :)

Answer (score 30):

When you call `$("#RequestCreateForm").submit()`, the script will just run through the event handler again, and cause an infinite loop (as Koen pointed out in a comment on the accepted answer). So, you need to remove the event handler before submitting:

```
$("#RequestCreateForm").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff, and if it's okay:
    $(this).off('submit').submit();
});
```

The last line needs to be in a conditional statement, otherwise it'll just always happen, and negate your `e.preventDefault();` at the top.

Comment: Excellent! this if it is functional to CONTINUE a form that has been stopped.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#RequestCreateForm").submit(function (e) {
    if ($("#RequestCreateForm").validate().checkForm() == false) 
    { 
         e.preventDefault();
         return false; 
    }        

    //other scripts

}
```

Answer (score 1):

All solutions here are too complicated or lead to javascript error, simpliest and ***clearest*** solution I guess:

```
jQuery("#formid").submit(function(e) {
        if( ! (/*check form*/)  ){  //notice the "!"
          e.preventDefault();
          //a bit of your code
        } //else do nothing, form will submit
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#RequestCreateForm").submit(function (e) {
    if ($("#RequestCreateForm").validate().checkForm() == false) { return; }

    e.preventDefault();

    //many scripts

    // Bypass the jquery form object submit and use the more basic vanilla
    // javascript form object submit

    $("#RequestCreateForm")[0].submit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid submit loops, an additional variable should be used.

```
var codeExecuted = false;
$('#RequestCreateForm').submit(function(e) {
    ...
    if(!codeExecuted){
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
        functionExecuted = true;
        $(this).trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to avoid the infinite loop.

- In the form, I use a "button" with an id (e.g. `<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>`) to mimic the submit button;
- In the script I have something like this:

> ```
> $('#submit').click(function() {
>   if(//validation rules is ok)
>   {
>       $("#RequestCreateForm").submit(); //assuming the form id is #RequestCreateForm
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       return false;
>   }
> });
> ```

Answer (score -1):

return; is the same thing as e.preventDefault();

try

```
$("#RequestCreateForm").trigger('submit');
```

Comment: `return` is not the same as `e.preventDefault();`. `return` also is `e.stopPropagation();` which kills events that bubble up.  `e.preventDefault();` still allows events to bubble up, hence the difference.