# Jquery custom Form Validation

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to create a custom validation form but i dont know how to do it. On submit of the form I want to add the "warning_red" class to an input if the input is empty. Also i would like to remove the placeholder of the input elements and replace is with a "required" text. I can achieve that but using "required" in my html but i would like to know the way with jQuery. Hope someone can help.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Name">
            <br>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <br>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <br>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
        </form>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:9px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

input {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    width:200px;
    margin:20px 0;
}


.warning_red {
    color:#ff0000;
    background:#d89d9d;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(function(){
         $("#submit_btn").on("click", function(){
             var texta = $(".wrapper").find("input");
         if (texta.val()==="") {
             texta.addClass("warning_red");
            }
         });  
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not test it but you want something like this. Firstly you have to add an ID to the button and the jquery is something like this

```
 <div class="wrapper" id="id1"> 

   $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#SubmitButton").click(function() {

             var text = $('div#id1');
        text.find('input').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).val())
            {
              text.addClass( "warning_red" );
            }
          });
          });
          });
```

Comment: I have test it but its not working, and i have change the #wrapper to .wrapper.

Comment: Add these scripts, I'm working on it 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have made some changes to the code and its working but it does not prevent it from submitting the form. It just add the class and then the form executes.

Comment: Check this answer, I will edit my code too, to give you the recursive check of all inputs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113560/jquery-stop-submitting-form-perform-script-continue-submitting-form

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
   <div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="vaildation_available" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Name">
        <br>
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input  class="vaildation_available" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last    Name">
        <br>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="vaildation_available" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <br>
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input class="vaildation_available" type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_btn"  value="Submit">
    </form>
```

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
     $( '.vaildation_available' ).each(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).addClass('warning_red');
      }
     });
   });        
  });
```